# Delay AppDomain recycle on folder change

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I am developing a ASP.NET 4 app and use full IIS also during development (for several reasons; one that I use multiple domains pointing to the app).

When I build the project in Visual Studio IIS does recycle the AppDomain and loads the newly built one, but now I have the problem, that it does this "to fast".
I have some scripts on my page which trigger an App-Startup as soon as it is recycled (like constantly open SignalR channels) and so a new AppDomain is already created when only half of my project is built and so it recycles a second time which then actually crashes, because I have a `PreApplicationStartMethod` copying some Plugin-DLL's to a Shadow-Copy directory, but the "old DLL's" are still locked by the first AppDomain.
If I then wait ~10s everything is fine and my "new AppDomain" starts up.
I though of solving this problem by simply telling IIS to wait with the rececly for a few seconds so the build can complete after it detects the changes in the `bin` folder.

So to my main question:
**Is it possible to delay an AppDomain recycle under IIS?**

Comment: If it is just a lock problem, did you try to `Disable Overlapped Recycle` to avoid two simultaneous worker process ?

Answer (score 14):

If you can't delay the AppDomain recycle, you may want to disable it.

There is a **File Change Notification (FCN)** behavior which can be disabled.

**Registry**

Originally, it is a DWORD registry entry at `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\ASP.NET\FCNMode`, [setting the value to 1 should disable it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911272/en-us).

**Code (hack) up to .NET Framework 4.0**

This **hack** might work with 2.0-3.5 and 4.0 frameworks.

```
//Disable AppDomain restart on file change

System.Reflection.PropertyInfo p = 
    typeof(System.Web.HttpRuntime).GetProperty("FileChangesMonitor", 
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic 
        | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public 
        | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);

object fcm = p.GetValue(null, null);

System.Reflection.MethodInfo m = fcm.GetType().GetMethod("Stop",
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance 
    | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic); 
m.Invoke(fcm, new object[] { });
```

Drop it in your `Global.asax` `Application_Start`. See [here](http://dot-net-web-developer-bristol.blogspot.fr/2010/04/disabling-file-change-notification-fcn.html).

If you want to disable the monitoring for specific paths or files you can use `StopMonitoringFile` or `StopMonitoringPath` methods from [`FileChangesMonitor`](http://dotnetinside.com/framework/v4.0.30319/System.Web/FileChangesMonitor). However, `Bin` directory is a special dir and may be immune to these two methods.

At least, you can play with the `_dirMonSpecialDirs` field and call `StopMonitoring()` on your `Bin` directory.

**.NET Framework 4.5**

In .NET Framework 4.5, a [HttpRuntimeSection.FcnMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.fcnmode.aspx) property exists. There is not so much documentation about it but you can use `<httpRuntime fcnMode="Disabled"/>`.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but according to the image in the article I linked it should work that way. I also wanted to avoid disabling FCNs, but I could try it to be shure it is actually the cause of my problem...

Comment: I can confirm that <httpRuntime fcnMode="Disabled"/> DOES work in 4.5. Thanks!

Comment: <httpRuntime fcnMode="Disabled"/> does not work for me.  Or does it not apply to changes made to the web.config file?  My application pool is still being reset if I change the web.config file.

Answer (score 2):

Found an article explaining this:
http://www.ipreferjim.com/2012/04/asp-net-appdomains-and-shadow-copying/

The settings I searched for are `waitChangeNotification` and `maxWaitChangeNotification` as attributes to `httpRuntime`.

Sadly it seems to not have solved my problem - need to investigate more...